# OpenLDAP VS Active Directory as a back-end DB?

Tags: radius

I'm working on a project and I need to make the clients authenticate themselves by using 802.1x, I'm using RADIUS as an Authentication Server, my question is what is the best choice as a back-end Database for RADIUS, is it openLDAP or Active Directory?

What is the pros and cons of both implementations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: mysql, postgres, etc. Unless there's other reasons to setup LDAP, there's no point using RADIUS to relay to LDAP. It's just adding complexity.

Comment: We have big LDAP DB so we have to use LDAP ,, My question is do I have to replace it by AD ,is AD better than LDAP or not? thanks @RickyBeam

Comment: Use what you already have, if it works for you. Also, some systems can auth directly to LDAP. (you haven't said what hardware you're using.)

Comment: This is like asking what routing protocol to use. The right answer is the one you have. Moving from LDAP to AD is non trivial and a bad idea unless you really, really, really have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a useful PDF which answer this question and which explain in details the advantages of openLDAP over Active Directrory

http://symas.com/documents/Adam-Eval1-0.pdf

Comment: Some more data on why Active Directory is inferior
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKm6zXzOHGc